# Bootstrap Borders and Background Not Showing in a DIV

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, border

Trying to add a border to my index box, but having trouble.

Right now when using display: inline-table the border shows up, but breaks the design when resizing.

When using display block or no display at all, it resizes perfectly, but borders and background color disappears.

```
#borda {
   border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   clear: both;
   display: inline-table;
}
```

and my html:

```
<body>
   <div class="container"> 
      <div id="borda"> 
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
           Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
           Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Much appreciated for help, just starting using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have one extra closing  in the markup above. Correct (remove) that.

Second, you should always wrap col-* class divs with .row div.

Third, you have to specify other media query classes for your layout to work properly when you resize your browser.

This should be what you need:

```
<div class="container"> 
      <div id="borda"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> 
               Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> 
               Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YhV6k/